# flutter: Can I adjust the width or height of the CupertinoAlertDialog(iOS style)?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter. I want a iOS style app so I use CupertinoAlertDialog. But I want to customize its height and width. Is that possible? Here is what I have done.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Pick Me !!!"),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => Center(
                child: CupertinoAlertDialog (
                  title: new Text("drop out"),
                  content: new Text("quit the window"),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Cancle!'),
                      onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(_);
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('OK'),
                      onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(_);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            );
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter, the `CupertinoAlertDialog` widget is designed to `follow Apple's iOS design guidelines`, and it does not provide `properties to customize its height and width`. You have to use `AlertDialog` if you want to archive height and width.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom-sized Alert Dialog'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Show Custom-sized Alert Dialog'),
          onPressed: () {
            showCustomSizedAlertDialog(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showCustomSizedAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 300, // Set the width as desired
            height: 200, // Set the height as desired
            child: AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Custom-sized Alert Dialog'),
              content: Text('This is a custom-sized alert dialog.'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```